# How to add event in google calendars to user who fill the google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I want that if some people fill the google form, the new event fall in his google calendar. How it is possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web site I used to do the exact thing.

http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event

Follow the steps and its not to bad.